# Unsure of how to catch and reassign synthetic members in a class

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I'm currently using the jacoco maven plugin in my project. I've written my unit tests using mockito. I've read the jacoco FAQs, the Google Groups page, and the Jacoco github issues threads about catching synthetic member fields in a Unit Test class and reassigning them as the jacoco injected object doesn't know what to do with synthetic members.

However a great many of my unit tests are setup and mocked using the mockito framework, and I don't think Jacoco likes the MockMvc object class. I think the class itself is implemented somehow using reflection which is causing jacoco to fail.

My error when I run mvn test is:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is my.project.submodule.controller.ControllerException: Unknown property '$jacocoData'
```

My code snippet that's triggering this is:

```
mockMvc.perform(
            get("/api/substituteStuff"))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(10)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
```

Answer (score 2):

> I think the class itself is implemented somehow using reflection which is causing jacoco to fail.

There are many cases in which compiler can generate [synthetic members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Member.html#isSynthetic--), for one of examples - presence of `assert`ions in class. And this will cause the same failure, so this is not JaCoCo failure, but failure of your code/library. Solution is to update your code or library to ignore such members.

Quoting http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/faq.html :

> #### My code uses reflection. Why does it fail when I execute it with JaCoCo?
>
> To collect execution data JaCoCo instruments the classes under test
>   which adds two members to the classes: A private static field
>   $jacocoData and a private static method $jacocoInit(). Both members
>   are marked as synthetic.
>
> Please change your code to ignore synthetic members. This is a good
>   practice anyways as also the Java compiler creates synthetic members
>   in certain situation.

And as a workaround - exclude class from instrumentation.